# Graph the all the combinations of $cu+dv$ with the restrictions of $c$ and $d$

Tags: graphing-functions

Graph the all the combinations of $cu+dv$ with the restrictions of $c$ and $d$ are integers (both positive and negative )

[image]

i draw this is it right ?

Comment: So $u,v$ are vectors on a 2D plane?

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Juan_Archilla-US/publication/6673591/figure/fig9/AS:319455524605955@1453175540730/Scheme-of-the-2D-lattice-used-for-DB-calculation-a1-and-a2-are-the-base-vectors.png). Just replace $a_1, a_2$ with $u,v$. Since your multipliers are always integers you get a lattice like structure. What you have written is the formula for a general point in a bravis lattice in 2D with $u,v$ being the basis vectors.